# How to retrieve files inside folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsom

I need to retrieve pages that is in the file "Folder". Doc/Folder/

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Doc');
```

When I do this it works but it doesn't go in my file, of course, because I didn't specify it. So when I do this:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Doc/Folder');
```

That doesn't work! I created my pages that I put in that Folder..

Answer (score 1):

Here are the couple of ways of doing it. Taken from my blog post : [Get Files from folder using JavaScript client object model](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/11/sharepoint-get-files-from-folder-using.html)
***using  SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()***

```
var allItems;
function GetFilesFromFolder(listTitle, folderServerRelativeUrl)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    // Use createAllItemsQuery to get items inside subfolders as well. Otherwise use new SP.CamlQuery() to get items from a single folder only
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(folderServerRelativeUrl);
    allItems = list.getItems(query);
    context.load(allItems, 'Include(File, FileSystemObjectType)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailure));
}
function OnSuccess()
{                                              
    var listItemEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
    while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var currentItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();                                                                                                                     
        if(currentItem.get_fileSystemObjectType() == "0")
        {
            var file = currentItem.get_file();
            if(file != null)
            {
                alert('File Name: ' + file.get_name() + '\n' + 'File Url: ' + file.get_serverRelativeUrl());                                                                                     
            }
        }
    }                                              
}

function OnFailure(sender, args) {
    alert("Failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}
```

**Using Folder.get_files();**

```
    var files;
    function getFilesInFolder(folderServerRelativeUrl) {        
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderServerRelativeUrl);
        files = folder.get_files();
        context.load(files);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailure));
    }
    function OnSuccess()
    {                                              
        var listItemEnumerator = files.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var fileUrl = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_serverRelativeUrl();             
            }                                         
    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
        alert("Failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function on your Ecmascript file. (Sharepoint 2010 or 2013)

```
 function getLibraryFiles(listName, url, callback){
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(url);
    var allItems = list.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(allItems, 'Include(ContentType, File, FileLeafRef, ServerUrl)');     
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args){
        var file, item, itemsEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
        var result = new Array();
        while (itemsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            item = itemsEnumerator.get_current();
            var r = {   
                Title: item.get_item('Title'),
                ContentType: item.get_item('ContentType'),
                File: item.get_item('File'),
                FileLeafRef: item.get_item('FileLeafRef'),
                ServerUrl: item.get_item('ServerUrl')
            };
            if(item.get_contentType().get_name() === 'Folder')
            {
                r.type='d';
                r.name=r.FileLeafRef
            } else {
                r.type='f';
                file = item.get_file();
                if(file!=null){
                    r.url=file.get_serverRelativeUrl();
                    r.name=file.get_name();
                    r.created=file.get_timeCreated();
                }
            }
            result.push(r);
        }
        callback(result);
    });
  }
```

The URL variable should be made dynamic if you wish to get documents from other library.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Doc');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllFoldersQuery();
var folders = list.getItems(query);
```

Source: [Get all Folders using Ecmascript\Javascript client object model SharePoint 2010](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/09/10/get-all-folders-using-ecmascriptjavascript-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/)